# Removing Linear Referencing labels after removing layers?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, route

How does one remove Labels after adding one from Linear Referencing tab in the Find Window of ArcMap 10.4.1? Removed feature but the labels remain

The labels in the find window and under the Linear Referencing tab are displayed even though the Feature has been removed

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.

Answer (score 1):

These labels are just graphic elements on the screen.

You can select these graphics using the Select Elements arrow [image], and then just hit <kbd>Del</kbd>

[image]